# Licensing Cover-Art For Book

Tags: licensing

I'm a graphic artist digital and print/front-end designer and developer. Recently I was approached by a friend to design cover art for his book. He had informed me he couldn't offer me a payment but would offer credit towards my work within his book.

I don't mind doing the work as a favor however I wanted to ask for royalties on books sold. As I am new to licensing artwork i'm not sure what to charge for royalties or what steps I need to take to protect my artwork. Any advice or information on how to proceed within this dilemma would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whatever you decide, **WRITE UP A CONTRACT**. You must both sign it before you begin work. The contract should contain your requirements for licensing and state that you own the copyright otherwise. You can probably find some good language as a starting point from AIGA: http://www.aiga.org

Do not in any way proceed without a contract. Even if your contract is written in crayon and says "my buddy Joe can use my artwork for anything ever, including a tattoo on his arse, as long he pays me in unicorn feathers," get your agreement with him in writing and with both your signatures.

How much to charge is a market decision.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! AIGA proved most helpful and provided alot of the answers I was looking for.